# Html.DisplayFor not generating a TextBox in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to move away from hard coding things like text boxes. I'm using MVC3 and I'm doing a very simple test:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.TestProperty)
    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.TestProperty)
}
```

LabelFor correctly displays the label. Nothing is generated for the DisplayFor property. Am I missing something? I've done some extensive googling, but I can't figure out why nothing is being generated, must be a simple mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A display template (`Html.DisplayFor`) is used (as it name suggests) for displaying a value. If you want editing the value with a textbox you need an editor template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.TestProperty)
```

Comment: Gave it a +1 and accepted the answer. You can't accept answer for 12 minutes, which is annoying when you get a quick answer.